# how to access the disparity value in opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

Which of the option is correct

```
disparity.at<short>(X,Y)
disparity.at<uchar>(X,Y)
```

Do we have to divide the disparity by 16.0 to get the correct disparity.
some people in their blog uses 1. Some have used 2 .The type is of short using the function disparity.type().
The disparity value which I am getting by accessing using 1 is very high.

Comment: I can't see any difference between 1 & 2. Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry missed it ...i am eiting...I was writing inside<> without using the insert code option

Comment: where did you get the disparity values from? Kinect capture libraries typically deliver 16 Bit unsigned values (but depth, not disparity), which would be `.at<short>` other methods might compute `<uchar>` values or maybe even `<float>` or something else. You can try to print `disparity.depth` and tell us. One more thing to mention: If your X and Y are image notation X and Y then your access is wrong and should either be `.at<type>(Y,X)` or `.at<type>(cv::Point(X,Y))`

Comment: i have two stereo pair images from KITTI dataset. I am finding disparity using stereoBM  given in opencv.

Comment: if you created it with `StereoMatcher::compute` you can have a look at the doc: `disparity – Output disparity map. It has the same size as the input images. Some algorithms, like StereoBM or StereoSGBM compute 16-bit fixed-point disparity map (where each disparity value has 4 fractional bits), whereas other algorithms output 32-bit floating-point disparity map.` which is a 16 bit type, so <uchar> should definitely be wrong. Not sure about that fixed-point 4 fractional bit things http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereomatcher-compute

Comment: All I want is to calculate the pixel disparity (This point in image 1 is **x** pixel away from its stereo pair).I have calculated the disparity using stereoBM.

Comment: have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereobm-operator ... you can select between float or 16S type. Documentation says that if you choose 16S type you HAVE to divide each value by 16. Probably that's to use the full 16S precision during disparity computation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use OpenCV 2.4.x you have to look at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereobm-operator which tells you:

> disparity – Output disparity map. It has the same size as the input images. When disptype==CV_16S, the map is a 16-bit signed single-channel image, containing disparity values scaled by 16. To get the true disparity values from such fixed-point representation, you will need to divide each disp element by 16. If disptype==CV_32F, the disparity map will already contain the real disparity values on output.

So if you've chosen `disptype = CV_16S` during computation, you can access a pixel at pixel-position (X,Y) by:

```
short pixVal = disparity.at<short>(Y,X);
```

while the disparity value is

```
float disparity = pixVal / 16.0f;
```

if you've chosen `disptype = CV_32F` during computation, you can access the disparity directly:

```
float disparity = disparity.at<float>(Y,X);
```

Accessing the disparity matrix with `.at<uchar>` should definitely be wrong!

please be aware that there might be differences for different OpenCV versions!

Comment: Thanks for the answer ....I was using (X,Y) instead of (Y,X) and getting deg faults ....Thanks a lot

Comment: have fun! It's a bit confusing that `.at` accesses in `(Y,X)` order but that's because it is a matrix and mathematical matrix convention is to index row first before column. While images typically have X-Axis-first to access a pixel.

Answer (score 1):

With `StereoBM` the output disparity can be `CV_16S` or `CV_32F`. When disparity's type is `CV_16S`, then it is a 16-bit signed single-channel image, containing disparity values scaled by 16. To get the true disparity values from such fixed-point representation, you will need to divide each element by 16. If disparity's type is `CV_32F`, then the disparity map will already contain the real disparity values on output.